# Magento 1.8.1 can't connec to Redis server 2.8.19-1

Tags: magento-1.8, nginx, redis

I've been struggling with this one (of course!) for a while. Can't wrap my brain around it.

Magento just won't connect to the REDIS server.
Since i'm getting not errors but a "there has been an error processing your request message" I was forced to put "Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);" in the index.php (in the magento root) to view the error.

This is the error i'm not getting:

```
Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.

#0 /usr/share/nginx/html/lib/Credis/Client.php(412): Credis_Client->connect()
#1 /usr/share/nginx/html/lib/Credis/Client.php(674): Credis_Client->connect()
#2 /usr/share/nginx/html/lib/Credis/Client.php(573): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)
#3 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/community/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(125): Credis_Client->select(0)
#4 /usr/share/nginx/html/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)
#5 /usr/share/nginx/html/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)
#6 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(137): Zend_Cache::factory('Varien_Cache_Co...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true)
#7 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->__construct(Array)
#8 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/Mage.php(463): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core/cache', Array)
#9 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(401): Mage::getModel('core/cache', Array)
#10 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCache(Array)
#11 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#12 /usr/share/nginx/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

I'm using a copy of CentOS 6.5 running on VMplayer.

I've have everything setup with:

NGINX > PHP-FPM > MAGENTO 1.8.1 > MYSQL > REDIS

Here's the version of what's i'm running:

```
nginx-1.6.2-1.el6.ngx.x86_64
redis-2.8.19-1.el6.remi.x86_64
php-pecl-redis-2.2.5-1.el6.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-fpm-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
```

My NGINX configuration:

```
user nginx nginx;

worker_processes  2;
pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
        include                 /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type            application/octet-stream;

        include /etc/nginx/custom.d/http_level/*.conf;

        error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log  error;

        log_format      custom  '{ "@timestamp": "$time_iso8601", "webserver_remote_addr": "$remote_addr", "webserver_remote_user": "$remote_user", "webserver_body_bytes_sent": $body_bytes_sent, "webserver_request_time": $request_time, "webserver_status": "$status", "webserver_request": "$request", "webserver_request_method": "$request_method", "webserver_http_referrer": "$http_referer", "webserver_http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent" }';


        access_log             /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;

        server_tokens           off;

        proxy_read_timeout      7200;
        fastcgi_read_timeout    7200;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

        sendfile                on;
        tcp_nopush              on;
        tcp_nodelay             on;
        keepalive_timeout       120;
        client_max_body_size    120m;

        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_types text/javascript text/css application/xml application/x-javascript application/javascript;

        variables_hash_max_size 1024;
        variables_hash_bucket_size 128;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;  # don’t use SSLv3 ref: POODLE



        upstream php53_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com {
            server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }


        # mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com
        map $http_host $magento_multistore_key_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com {
                default default;
                www.mydomain.com en_us;

        }

        map $http_host $magento_multistore_type_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com {
                default store;
                www.mydomain.com store;

        }

        server {
            listen              127.0.0.1:80;
            server_name         mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
            root                /usr/share/nginx/html/;



        include /etc/nginx/custom.d/server_level/*.conf;



            location ~* ^/(server-status|whm-server-status) {
                stub_status on;
                access_log   off;
                allow 10.10.221.2;
                allow 10.10.221.3;
                allow 192.168.209.129;
                allow 10.10.17.108;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
            }

            location /php-fpm-status {
                access_log   off;
                allow 10.10.221.2;
                allow 10.10.221.3;
                allow 192.168.209.129;
                allow 127.0.0.1;

                fastcgi_pass php53_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
            }

            # Direct download
            location ~* ^/(js|static|skin|media|images)/ { expires 1w; }
            location /errors/ { }
            location ~* ^/errors/.*\.xml$ { deny all; }
            location ~* ^/errors/.*\.phtml$ { deny all; }

            # Deny
            location ~* /(\.ht|\.svn|\.git) { deny all; }
            location ~* ^/(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { deny all; }

            # 503 error page
#           error_page 500 502 503 504 /503.html;
#           fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
#           location = /503.html { }

            autoindex off;

            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                index index.php index.html;
                access_log off;
            }

            location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|css|js|ico|swf)$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php;
                expires 1w;
                access_log off;
            }

            location @proxy {
                try_files $uri =404; # if reference to php executable is invalid return 404
                expires off;
                fastcgi_pass php53_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com;
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;


                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }

            location ~\.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404; # if reference to php executable is invalid return 404
                expires off;
                fastcgi_pass php53_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com;
                fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;

                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $magento_multistore_key_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com;
                fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $magento_multistore_type_mydomain_com_www_mydomain_com;
            }
        }
}
```

My REDIS config has the usual bind 127.0.0.1 on port 6379 (i've verified that it's listening, and it is)

```
[root@www cache]# netstat -anp | grep -i 6379
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      47642/redis-server  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26379  7905/Xorg           @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

And finally my magento local.xml file:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
<cache>
  <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
  <backend_options>
    <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
    <port>6379</port>
    <persistent></persistent> <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
    <database>0</database> <!-- Redis database number; protection against accidental data loss is improved by not sharing databases -->
    <password></password> <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
    <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
    <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures; a value of 1 will not retry after the first failure -->
    <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration; phpredis does not currently support setting read timeouts -->
    <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
    <compress_data>1</compress_data>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
    <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>  <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
    <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
    <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf, lz4 (as l4z) and snappy -->
    <use_lua>0</use_lua> <!-- Set to 1 if Lua scripts should be used for some operations -->
  </backend_options>
</cache>
```

Please tell me i'm not going crazy :)

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Please try connecting to your redis server with an independent client to make sure that much works.

Comment: `[root@www html]# redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379
127.0.0.1:6379>` Sure does work :( unfortunetely.

Comment: Can you try that while su'ed to your web server user please?  Just wanna rule that out.  Thanks.

Comment: I've started my NGINX process with root instead of NGINX user. `[root@www html]# ps -efw | grep nginx
root      72961      1  0 12:51 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
root      72963  72961  0 12:51 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process                   
root      72964  72961  0 12:51 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process                   
`

Comment: Anyone else? I just don't get it :(

Comment: Your version of Magento will support the MAGE namespace  <backend><![CDATA[Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis]]></backend>